# Why Is My MemoryCache Duplicating Objects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor, memorycache

I have a Blazor Server Side application that is running a Singleton object through which Transient Blazor pages can add and retrieve cached data.  In the current project, there are only supposed to be three objects in total but, when I look via the Memory Diagnostics tool, I literally see 60+ objects which are all duplicates from what I can determine.  I must be screwing something up but I just cannot figure out what.  Any help would be amazing as, otherwise, I am going to have to use NCache (running on Windows Servers) which is complete overkill for this demo app.

Here is everything:

```
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddSingleton<IBearCacheManager, BearCacheManager>();
```

```js
namespace vBear_Frontend.Services
{
    public interface IBearCacheManager
    {
        object GetCacheObject(CacheType CurrentType);
        void AddUpdateCache(CacheType CurrentType, object CacheValue);
        void Dispose();
    }
}

using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Threading;

namespace vBear_Frontend.Services
{
    public enum CacheType
    {
        LocalSystem,
        GlobalBoolean
    }

    public class BearCacheManager : IBearCacheManager, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
        static readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim lockerForCache = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
        private const string LocalSystemCacheName = "LocalSystemStore";
        private const string GlobalBooleanCacheName = "GlobalBoolStore";

        public BearCacheManager(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
        {
            _cache = memoryCache;
        }

        public object GetCacheObject(CacheType CurrentType)
        {
            object someObject = null;
            try
            {
                lockerForCache.EnterReadLock();
                if (CurrentType == CacheType.LocalSystem)
                    _cache.TryGetValue(LocalSystemCacheName, out someObject);
                else
                    _cache.TryGetValue(GlobalBooleanCacheName, out someObject);
            }
            catch { }
            finally
            {
                if (lockerForCache.IsReadLockHeld)
                    lockerForCache.ExitReadLock();
            }
            return someObject;
        }

        public void AddUpdateCache(CacheType CurrentType, object CacheValue)
        {
            try
            {
                lockerForCache.EnterWriteLock();

                if(CurrentType == CacheType.LocalSystem)
                    _cache.CreateEntry(LocalSystemCacheName).SetValue(CacheValue).SetAbsoluteExpiration(DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(10)); 
                else
                    _cache.CreateEntry(GlobalBooleanCacheName).SetValue(CacheValue).SetAbsoluteExpiration(DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(10)); 
            }
            catch 
            {
                
            }
            finally
            {
                if (lockerForCache.IsWriteLockHeld)
                    lockerForCache.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            try
            {
                _cache.Dispose();
                if (lockerForCache.IsWriteLockHeld)
                    lockerForCache.ExitWriteLock();
                if (lockerForCache.IsReadLockHeld)
                    lockerForCache.EnterReadLock();
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

This Manager is then called by other Singleton and Scoped objects as well as Blazor pages via Dependency Injection.  When I place a breakpoint on the AddUpdateCache, it does go through that step several times as expected but then I see a ton of entries in the memory output.

[image: Screenshot of Memory Diagnostic for Cache]

I then thought that perhaps the cache was adding everything to the cache - including pages and service objects but I cannot figure out a) if that it true and b) how to prevent that caching from occurring.

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: What are you storing in the cache? None of the entries in RuntimeTypeCache are related to MemoryCache to my knowledge.  They are most likely at-runtime types that are cached internally to make Blazor rendering more efficient.

Comment: I was looking at the incorrect memory object - this one is full of all objects in the framework.  My actual cache is quite small BUT there are 81K+ objects rendered during Debug with a size of 8GB.  In Production, the entire system runs around 80MB - how do I get rid of that overhead?